# Lost windows while dual boot with ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

I have genuine windows 10 in my lappy. I tried to dual boot with Ubuntu but accidentally I replaced my windows with ubuntu. So now I have only ubuntu in my pc and I lost my genuine windows. How to get back my windows OS.I dont even have my back up image of my windows

Comment: do you have a licence serial number of some kind?

Comment: @Seth I think this question, no matter how well asked (or not) and how well responded to (or not) is not a duplicate, as they are asking how to recover a previous partition and the answer you linked to only shows how to do a new install. One of the answers here is quite useful, the one from Edid about http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

Comment: @JimLohse We actually have a duplicate for that too :)

Answer (score 2):

If you really deleted the Windows partition, Ubuntu is not going to get it back for you. Sorry.

Not knowing if this computer originally came with Windows 10, I will make the assumption it's fairly new and did. You could post more info per https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask :>)

When you start there should be a recovery partition. Look for the option to choose a boot device, perhaps F12, hold that key down and see if a recovery partition is a choice for bootup. Some computers hide this info at the start, and it's manufacturer specific, so you should consult your computer manual, again we don't know what model you have.

If you really overwrote everything then your best best is likely to contact the manufacturer. I am not aware that you can download windows 10 cold from the Internet. If for example you bought it from Best Buy or another retailer perhaps they can help.

This is probably a question for a more Windows oriented StackExchange site like https://superuser.com/

The only option that's relevant to askubuntu is that you could open a terminal window and run the command `fdisk -l` and see if there's still a recovery partition. If you are not familiar with Linux be very careful running fdisk, you should not need to use `sudo` to get this listing.

Comment: My last line is the answer :) I will edit, thanks

Comment: @Ron Yes, this answer does provide a (very good) answer. Upvoting.

Comment: @JimLohse then please make it the first line ;) this wasn't there when I posted my comment ;)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the feedback as a relative newb to AskUbuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Download testdisk from : http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download unpack it, launch ubuntu from live, change to folder where testdisk was unpacked and run:

```
sudo ./testdisk_static
```

from program menu chose analyse and try to recover your partition

This tutorial will help:
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

It will be hard, or even not possible but worth to try.

Comment: Awesome suggestion @EdiD in your experience how often does this actually work, given that the Windows 10 partition was probably overwritten with actual data? I never heard of this tool thanks for posting this answer

Comment: @JimLohse - I was successful with this program in past. I am quite sure it will see win 10 lost partition and maybe it will recover. It does not hurt to try

Comment: Oh totally agreed, thanks, I am still trying to figure out on this site how to gauge user skill levels so I think between our two answers we have the gamut covered :)