# deleted files recovery

Tags: windows, data-recovery, testdisk

I accidentally deleted one of partitions from the Ubuntu livecd. I get afraid and recreated the partition. But it was formated and all my files were gone. I installed Ubuntu in another partition.

Is there any way to recover the files from the partition. I searched Google and found an application called 'testdisk'. Will it solve my problem?

If yes how to do it (I am new to Ubuntu)

If no suggest anything else please...

Will installing Windows and using apps like 'advance data recovery' help me...?

Comment: Yes, testdisk is what you should try;  http://askubuntu.com/questions/724698/lost-windows-while-dual-boot-with-ubuntu/724701#724701

Comment: I deleted the partition and recreated it...then it will be OK..?

Comment: Do I have to delete partition again and proceed or keeping the recreated partition..?

Comment: You don't have to delete partition again, just launch the testdisk and try to recover it.

Comment: **Do your best not to write anything to the new partition.**  As long as you do not write anything to it `testdisk` should be able to find the data.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have deleted the partition, it's gone forever. Unless you have made a backup of the partition, then you can't get it back.